# How to reference an existing storage account created in Azure portal in an ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-storage-account

`

```html
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "InputstorageAccount": {
            "defaultValue": "inputstgdev",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "GitrepoBranch": {
           "type": "string",
           "defaultValue": "master",
           "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the branch to use when deploying (Default = master)."
            }
        },
        "GitrepoURL": {
           "type": "string",
           "defaultValue": "https://github.com/FBoucher/AzUnzipEverything.git",
           "metadata": {
                "description": "URL to repo (Default = master)."
            }
        },
        "InputcontainerName": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue": "inputcontainer",
          "metadata": {
            "description": "Specifies the name of the blob container."
          }
        },
        "OutputstorageAccount": {
            "defaultValue": "outputstgdev",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "OutputcontainerName": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue": "outputcontainer",
          "metadata": {
            "description": "Specifies the name of the blob container."
          }
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('InputstorageAccount'), '/default/', parameters('InputcontainerName'))]",
            "properties": {
                "publicAccess": "None"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('OutputstorageAccount'), '/default/', parameters('OutputcontainerName'))]",
            "properties": {
                "publicAccess": "None"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "serviceplan",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "F1",
                "capacity": 1
            },
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "serviceplan"
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": "serviceplan"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "functionapp",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "kind": "functionapp",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', 'serviceplan')]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('InputstorageAccount'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', 'serviceplan')]",
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings": [
                        {
                            "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('InputstorageAccount'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(parameters('InputcontainerName'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('InputstorageAccount'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(parameters('InputcontainerName'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('InputstorageAccount'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(parameters('InputcontainerName'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
                            "value": "[toLower('functionapp')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                            "value": "~2"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
                            "value": "[reference(resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', 'applicationInsightsName'), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                            "value": "dotnet"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "resources":[
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                    "name": "web",
                    "type": "sourcecontrols",
                    "dependsOn": [
                      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('InputstorageAccount'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "RepoUrl": "[parameters('GitrepoURL')]",
                        "branch": "[parameters('GitrepoBranch')]",
                        "publishRunbook": true,
                        "IsManualIntegration": true
                    }
                }
            ]

        }
    ]
}
```

`I have a  storage account called **STGaccount** which I created with the Azure portal and would like to use ARM template to create a container called **inputcontainer** in this **STGaccount**. Each time I try to do so I get an error message saying that the storage account **STGaccount** I am trying to create with the ARM template already exist in the resource group....So i guess I am writing my ARM template in a way that it still creates a new storage account with a name similar to the one I already have in the resource group. What I actually want to do is to reference the already existing storage account in my ARM template such that i do not have to create a new one. 
Thanks in advance as I look forward to your response

Comment: Please edit your question and include your ARM template.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ARM template, this will help you to create a container in the existing Storage account.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageAccountName": {
            "defaultValue": "STGaccount",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "containerName": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue": "inputcontainer",
          "metadata": {
            "description": "Specifies the name of the blob container."
          }
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountName'), '/default/', parameters('containerName'))]",
            "properties": {
                "publicAccess": "None"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank very much @Jagrati. It worked. The issue I am actually facing is that I want to create a function app with ARM such that the ARM template references already existing storage accounts (inputstgdev and  outputstgdev) which I have already parameterized. I would like the ARM template to use the inputstgdev storage account as its attahced storage account such that it does not  have to create a new storage account. The source control of the function app is referenced to a Gitrepo. Here is my ARM template. Each time I run it in the devops pipeline it says this ....

Comment: 2020-06-11T22:31:03.1194796Z ##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource '/subscriptions/bea8ac84-24a4-4e53-9198-e3b0107547d4/resourceGroups/dev-rgp/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/functionapp/sourcecontrols/web' at line '1' and column '3069' doesn't depend on parent resource '/subscriptions/bea8ac84-24a4-4e53-9198-e3b0107547d4/resourceGroups/dev-rgp/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/functionapp'. Please add dependency explicitly using the 'dependsOn' syntax. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'.

Comment: I think you can ask this as separate question and mention your scenario and error there!

Comment: thanks Jagrati Modi-AIS .  I have done that here......How to reference already existing Azure Portal created storage accounts in an ARM template